# How to check if a command succeeded?

Tags: command-line

Is there any way to check if there is an error in executing a command?

Example :

```
test1=`sed -i "/:@/c connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ip:1521:$dataBase" $search`
valid $test1

function valid () {
  if $test -eq 1; then
    echo "OK"
    else echo "ERROR" 
  fi
}
```

I already tried do that but it seems it isn't working. I don't how do that.

Comment: Prefer **$(foo)** over backticks **\`foo\`**, because you can nest it, and it's easier to distinguish from apostrophes.

Comment: BTW, you need to define a function (`valid`) before you call it.

Comment: Related: [SC2015: Note that A && B || C is not if-then-else. C may run when A is true.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015)

Answer (score 559, accepted):

The return value is stored in `$?`. 0 indicates success, others indicates error.

```
some_command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

Like any other textual value, you can store it in a variable for future comparison:

```
some_command
retval=$?
do_something $retval
if [ $retval -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Return code was not zero but $retval"
fi
```

For possible comparison operators, see [`man test`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/test.1.html).

Comment: That's nice ...can i hold the output error ??!! , because in this case i have 2 error : command error "text" ex, file not found and my error "text" Which is in this case failed for example

Comment: @moata_u: you can store the value in a variable as shown in my answer.

Comment: @moata_u: You need to put a `;` before the `else` and `fi`: `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi

Comment: please follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/29412/error-checking

Comment: `man test` only shows information about the *external* test command, not the shell's builtin test command; see the shell's manual for that. In bash you can also get info on builtins and keywords with the `help` builtin; `help test`.

Comment: This is a [useless use of `test`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#test).

Comment: why doesn't `if [ $? ]; ...` work?

Comment: @Blauhirn `[ $? ]` (or equivalently, `test $?`) does not work because `$?` evaluates to a number (0, 1, etc.) which is not null. See the [docs for `test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html): "If EXPRESSION is omitted, ‘test’ returns false.  If EXPRESSION is a single argument, ‘test’ returns false if the argument is null and true otherwise."

Comment: How do you do this all inside of the test statement?

Answer (score 140):

If you only need to know if the command succeeded or failed, don't bother testing `$?`, just test the command directly. E.g.:

```
if some_command; then
    printf 'some_command succeeded\n'
else
    printf 'some_command failed\n'
fi
```

And assigning the output to a variable doesn't change the return value (well, unless it behaves differently when stdout isn't a terminal of course).

```
if output=$(some_command); then
    printf 'some_command succeded, the output was «%s»\n' "$output"
fi
```

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals explains `if` in more detail.

Comment: What if you want to do something other than branching like storing the boolean of whether it failed or not into a .ini? Then your output variable doesn't do that, but `$?` does, so you're incorrect in saying that testing the command directly is strictly better.

Comment: Assigning the output to a variable may change the return value when one uses `local` command, i.e. `local foo=$(false); echo $?;` produces `0` on the output. But `local` is only relevant inside of bash functions.

Comment: I can't seem to use an `else` with the variable example. Any idea why?

Comment: @Prometheus hard to say without seeing the code. Perhaps it incorrectly returns 0 in the case you considered a failure, or perhaps you added additional commands to the command substitution without using && between them.

Comment: I'm not used to bash scripting. Does the `if` require some brackets or anything? Can I just have... `if cd unreliable_dir; then`

Comment: @osullic `[` is a command that returns 0 to indicate true, and 1 to indicate false. `if` runs one or more commands and checks the return value of the last one. If it returns 0, it does the `then` block, otherwise it jumps to `else` (if any). So yes, `if cd dir; then` is correct and sensible code.

Answer (score 55):

```
command && echo OK || echo Failed
```

Comment: If `command` returns error on screen, how to hide it?

Comment: If `command` writes errors out to stderr, you can use the form `command 2> /dev/null && echo OK || echo Failed`. The `2> /dev/null` redirects stderr output to `/dev/null`. However, some utilities will write errors to stdout (even though this is bad practice). In this case you can omit the 2 from the redirection, but you will lose any output from the command. This method of checking success is good for simple ternary logic but for more complex behavior it's best to check `$?` for command success, or use the `if` block method outlined in @geirha's answer.

Comment: Note that this is not save in all cases. See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015

Answer (score 27):

`$?` should contain the exit status of the previous command, which should be zero for no error.

So, something like;

```
cd /nonexistant
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo failed
else
    echo success!
fi
```

for most cases, it's easier to use the `&&` construct to chain commands that need to depend on each other.  So `cd /nonexistant && echo success!` would *not* echo success because the command breaks before `&&`.  The corollary of this is `||`, where `cd /nonexistant || echo fail` *would* echo `fail` because `cd` failed (this becomes useful if you use something like `||exit`, which will end the script if the previous command failed).

Comment: That's nice ...can i hold the output error ??!! , because in this case i have 2 error : command error "text" ex, file not found and my error "text" Which is in this case failed for example

Comment: @moata_u, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Answer (score 8):

```
command && echo $? || echo $?
```

Comment: You mean `command; echo $?` ?

Comment: No, my line is correct, it gives the actual result code as a number regardless if success or failure.

Comment: Ok, please explain the differences of these to me: `true && echo $? || echo $?` / `true; echo $?` and `false && echo $? || echo $?` / `false; echo $?` -- you'll find, they do the exact same thing :D

Comment: Yes, the same result but without the condition. The original question asked was "How to check if a command succeeded?", this was based on previous answers. I guess a better example would be: `command && echo "success: $?" || echo "fail: $?"`

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that `if...then...fi` and `&&`/`||` type of approach deals with exit status returned by command we want to test( 0 on success ); however, some commands don't return  a non-zero exit status if command failed or couldn't deal with input. This means that the usual `if` and `&&`/`||` approaches won't work for those particular commands.

For instance, on Linux  GNU `file` still exits with 0 if it received a non-existing file as argument and `find` couldn't locate the file user specified.

```
$ find . -name "not_existing_file"                                          
$ echo $?
0
$ file ./not_existing_file                                                  
./not_existing_file: cannot open `./not_existing_file' (No such file or directory)
$ echo $?
0
```

In such cases, one potential way we could handle the situation is by reading `stderr`/`stdin` messages, e.g. those that returned by `file` command, or parse output of the command like in `find`. For that purposes, `case` statement could be used.

```
$ file ./doesntexist  | while IFS= read -r output; do                                                                                                                  
> case "$output" in 
> *"No such file or directory"*) printf "%s\n" "This will show up if failed";;
> *) printf "%s\n" "This will show up if succeeded" ;;
> esac
> done
This will show up if failed

$ find . -name "doesn'texist" | if ! read IFS= out; then echo "File not found"; fi                                                                                     
File not found
```

---

( This is a repost of my own answer on [related question at unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404094/85039) )

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in many other answers, a simple test of `$?` will do, like this

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then something; fi
```

If you want to test if the command **failed**, you can use a shorter version in `bash` (but perhaps overkill) as follows:

```
if (($?)); then something; fi
```

This works by using the `(( ))` arithmetic mode, so if the command returned `success`, i.e. `$? = 0` then the test evaluates to `((0))` which tests as `false`, otherwise it will return `true`.

To test for **success**, you could use:

```
if ! (($?)); then something; fi
```

but it's already not much shorter than the first example.

Answer (score 2):

For easier debugging, I make commands to only output errors with:

> [so](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/so) [-tag] [commands]

After that $? is 0 if success, otherwise failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure bash to exit if a command fails, useful to avoid checks after every command. Place this at beginning of your script:

```
set -e
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Prints the status of the last command

`if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo passed;else echo failed; (exit 1); fi;`

Section `echo passed` and `echo failed` can be modified to do whatever you want depending on the status of the last command.

#### Usage

```
echo test # supposed to pass
if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo passed;else echo failed; (exit 1); fi;
```

> passed

```
blahblah # supposed to fail
if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo passed;else echo failed; (exit 1); fi;
```

> failed

More fun using bash profile function:

```
function if_success() {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        "$@"
    fi
}

echo base_echo
> base_echo
if_success echo awesome
> awesome

blah_blah
> command not found
if_success echo awesome
>
```