# How to get nicer error-messages in this bash-script?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to catch any error when run a command in order to write a log-file / report

I've tried this code:

```
    function valid (){

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "$var1" ": status : OK" 
     else echo "$var1" ": status : ERROR"   
    fi
   }

function save(){

 sed -i "/:@/c connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ip:1521:$dataBase" $search
 var1="adding database ip"
 valid $var1

 sed -i "/connection.username/c connection.username=$name" #$search
 var1="addning database SID"
 valid $var1
}
save
```

The output looks like this:

```
adding database ip : status : OK
sed: no input file
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
adding database ip : status : OK
sed: no input file : status : ERROR"
```

or this:

```
adding database ip : status : OK
addning database SID : status : ERROR"
```

I've been trying, but it's not working with me. :(

Comment: Can you post syntaxically correct code? Your `valid()` function is missing `}`. What do you want to achieve? Replacing lines matching `:@` with `connec...database`? Or replace occurences of `:@` in string `$search` by the text?

Comment: thanks 4 reply , Replacing :@ with connec..database , but this is not the problem every thing is going fine the things that am asking is out put of execution these command..$search variable is the path of file that to be changed ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the former:

```
# run sed, capture any output
var1="$(sed -i "/connection.username/c connection.username=$name" $search)"
```

For the latter:

```
# run sed, discard all output but keep exit status
sed -i "/connection.username/c connection.username=$name" $search >/dev/null 2>&1
```

That said, `valid()` is... strange, to say the least.  I would write it as

```
# valid label [status]
# check status ($? if not provided) and log success/failure
function valid {
  if [[ ${2-$?} == 0 ]]; then
    echo "$1 : status : OK"
  else
    echo "$1 : status : ERROR"
  fi
}
```

Actually, I would do it a bit differently from the start:

```
# log label command [arguments...]
# run command, output success/failure to stderr.  If label is empty, use the
# command name:  'log "" echo hi' uses 'echo' as the label.
# log entries look like
#    label1 : status : OK
#    label2 : status : ERROR
#    Error output from foo:
#      Baz is broken; fix and try again.
log() {
  # save off label
  local label="${1:-$2}"
  shift # this removes $1 and shifts $2... to $1... so "$@" works later
  # run command, capture output
  # $(command) runs 'command' and substitutes its output
  # "$@" preserves quoting; $* would turn argument "foo bar" into two
  # arguments foo bar
  err="$("$@")"
  if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    status=OK
  else
    status=ERROR
  fi
  echo "$label : status : $status" >&2 # standard error
  if [[ $status == ERROR ]]; then
    # log output from command, indented for clarity
    echo "Error output from $2:"
    echo "$err" | sed 's/^/  /' >&2
  fi
}

save() {
  # this sed command is pedantically correct; if GNU sed lets you
  # do single-line 'c' commands as in the original, then go for it.
  # The backslash-return after the label argument is just for clarity;
  # 'log "foo" bar' works just as well.
  log "adding database ip" \
    sed -i "/:@/c\\
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ip:1521:$dataBase\\
." "$search"
  # using the original (GNU?) sed syntax
  log "adding database SID" \
    sed -i "/connection.username/c connection.username=$name" "$search"
}

save
```

I would also include a timestamp and program ID, etc. in a real program.

You should probably explore the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html) to learn more about writing shell scripts.  [The UNIX Programming Environment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013937681X)'s shell programming chapters don't cover `bash` extensions to the original Bourne shell, but are still useful for learning the "zen" of shell scripting.

Comment: that's perfect ,, thanks let me check that :),,thanks

Comment: geekosaur , can you edit your post and add some comment ! specially in log() function .

Comment: No problem; comments and example log output now added.

Comment: The quoting `a="$(echo foo bar baz)"` is useless - a needs still quoting. `f () { echo $1; }` might be a function. `f $a` will just display 'foo', while `f "$a"` will display 'foo bar baz'. Which is, what you get for `a=$(echo foo bar baz)`.

Comment: well , still facing same problem of out put (log) still hiding error message that i wrote, it just write sed error ,  [sed: no input file] i want it be like this [addning database SID : status : ERROR"] OR [addning database SID : status : ERROR"] ,,,,,,geekosaur i will try your genius script tomorrow ...

Comment: I recommend against using the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide for learning Bash. It doesn't teach good practice, and in some parts, it's just plain wrong. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide instead.

Comment: Thanks geirha ,,,mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is very nice ..easy . simple , practice

Comment: geekosaur you code work perfectly..good job

Comment: what is different between `local label=$1` and `local label="${1:-$2}"` , both of them do same job !

Comment: The second one says "if $1 is empty, substitute $2 instead"; so if you say `log "" sed ...`, the label will be `sed`.  It's just defining a convenient shorthand for `log sed sed ...` or whatever.

Comment: @geekosaur,why you are using `"$("$@")"` , i mean after command shift you already called `sed...` but when i delete `"$("$@")"` i always get OK even its error or ERROR even its OK...Please could you explain this point...

Comment: `"$(command)"` runs `command` and substitutes its output, preserving spaces, tabs, and newlines instead of the default of collapsing all of them to a single space.  `"$@"` substitutes the command line arguments (minus the label, which we `shift`ed away) with all quoting preserved.  So `"$("$@")"` means "run the command specified in the script's arguments and substitute its output" — which we then assign to `err` for later use.  (Where did you think I had called `sed`?  I use it later to indent the output from the command, but that is unrelated.)

Comment: @geekosaur , now every thing is clear 100% ,,but you know if i used command `ls` instead of `sed...` then  `"$("$@")"` would not work i already tried use `"$("$*")"` then it works ,, so there is an situation that i can use `"$("$*")"` instead of `"$("$@")"` ,, Thanks 4 ur time

Comment: How exactly did it not work?

Comment: its says `./cc: line 7: 0: command not found` , if you type `"$("$1 $2 $3 $4")"` instead ,out put comes but only 4 argument of output which mean that its run but out put not come out by using this command `"$("$@")"` or should i use it in different way !!

Comment: @geekosaur . my mistake every thing is ok now ....thanks