# If wget url fails, create fake file with name - url+fake.m3u8

Tags: scripts, wget

I made a script for checking the presence of `*.m3u8` files from `.csv` file.

If the link is absent the `*.m3u8` file is not downloaded.

How to do:

1. If the file download errors out, create an empty file with name - "file"+"fake".m3u8

for example:

```
wget http://ex.ua/files/heroes.m3u8`
```

this url is absent, so create file - `heroesfake.m3u8`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Oleksii You said, "If the link is absent..." Is that to say that you would prefer the "fake" file only be created when the download fails with a "404 not found" error? (This is not the only way a download could fail.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to check if a command succeeded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded)

For example:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
wget http://ex.ua/files/heroes.m3u8
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    touch heroes-fake.m3u8
fi
```

Comment: Thx, but I found:
wget -P "$DIR2" "$a" || touch -- "$DIR2$(basename "$a" "$EXT")fake$EXT"